# How to get C2D messages that are put in Dead Letter Queue (DLQ)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I'm using Azure IOT Hub and we will start sending C2D messages to some devices.
According to the documentation provided by Microsoft (available here: [The cloud-to-device message life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d#the-cloud-to-device-message-life-cycle)) a device can reject a message, which means that message will be put in a DLQ. It can also go to DLQ when expired.

Also, according to the same page, it is said that each device has its own queue with up to max 50 messages each.

My question is: How can we access the device's messages in Dead Letter Queue? I can't find anything in the documentation and the SDK.

I know that for any other service bus queue we can subscribe to its /$deadletterqueue but I can't find anything related to that for C2D messaging.

Comment: Since I still haven't get any reply I created an issue at github: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/110822